# Is it possible to reopen ParquetWriter after close() is called?

Tags: parquet, parquet-mr

I'm currently using `ParquetWriter` to write Avro records to parquet files. I can use the `write()` and `close()` methods to write and close files as needed. Now I have a use case where I need to reopen a closed file. I don't see such a method exists in `ParquetWriter`. Based on the Parquet specification, it seems possible to reopen a file. I'm wondering if there is any reason why we don't have a `reopen()` method implemented. Or is there any other classes that I could use to reopen a closed parquet file?

If I would like to implement such a method, could someone provide me with any guideline? Thanks.